# Building formula from scientific paper

Tags: r, formula

I am trying to build a mathematical formuala from a scientific paper into R.

In the example given, I used a variable of 164 microns. This was taken from the first result in Table 3 from the paper I have attached. You'll see in this table the current velocities calculated (pretty neat!).

The overall point of this, is that I wish to aquire two things: erosional velocity and depositional velocity. The paper I have attached does so using the formulae given. I am trying to build a package which can run hundreds of mean grain sizes (i.e. the variable) through these formulae. In an ideal world, my main goal is to build a code using the given formulae, which takes the variable (mean grain size) and spits out lovely data.... I think it is possible, but unfortunaley my R skills are inadequate

Link to formulae: https://imgur.com/a/DEN721v?

Link to original scietific paper: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00531-008-0312-5

There are 5 equations, all of which feed into each other. The outcome depends on one variable to which I input at the start.

I am given four known values:

- **p** (water density given as m^3),
- **ps** (grain density as m^3),
- **g** (acceleration due to gravity given as m/s^2),
- **v** (kinematic viscosity of water given as m^2/s)

and a variable (written as d) with is the mean grain size of a sediment sample.

- **d** Variable. The mean grain size of a sediment sample.

For example, if I had a mean grain size of 164μm this would be input as 1.64e-4.

Seeking help as my outcomes are definately not even close to what they should be.

```
p <- 1027.4     #water density (m^3)
ps <- 2650      #grain density (m^3)
g <- 9.81       #acceleration due to gravity (m/s^2)
v <- 1.4313e-6  #kinematic viscosity of water  (m^2/s)
z100 <- 100     #level above seabed (cms)
d <- 1.64e-4    #variable (mean grain size in microns)
```

EQUATION 1

```
D1 <- 9.81*(ps-p)
D2 <- (p*v)^2
D3 <- (D1/D2)
D4 <- D3^(1/3)
D5 <- D4*d

D <- D5          #Dimensionless grain size

D
```

EQUATION 2.3

```
1 - exp(-0.001374634317)

Tcr1 <- -0.020*D
Tcr2 <- 1 - exp(Tcr1)
Tcr3 <- 0.055*Tcr2
Tcr4 <- 0.30/1+(1.2*D)
Tcr5 <- Tcr4 + Tcr3
Tcr6 <- 9.81*(ps-p)
Tcr7 <- Tcr6*d
Tcr8 <- Tcr7*Tcr5

Tcr <- Tcr8 #threshold bed shear stress (N/m^2)
exp(Tcr1)

Tcr

Ucr1 <- Tcr/p
Ucr2 <- sqrt(Ucr1)

Ucr <- Ucr2     #critical shear velocity
```

EQUATION 3

```
z0 <- d/12      #roughness length

z0
```

EQUATION 4

```
Ue1 <- z100/z0
Ue2 <- Ucr/0.41
Ue3 <- log(Ue1)
Ue4 <- Ue2*Ue3

Ue <- Ue4  # critical current velocity erosional threshold from particle size distribution

Ue
```

EQUATION 5

```
Usetl1 <- 10.36^(2)
Usetl2 <- D^(3)
Usetl3 <- 1.049*Usetl2
Usetl4 <- Usetl1 + Usetl3
Usetl5 <- Usetl4^(1/2)
Usetl6 <- Usetl5 - 10.36
Usetl7 <- v/d
Usetl8 <- Usetl7*Usetl6

Usetl <- Usetl8
```

Results given as cm/s, and should be in and around 20-50 cm/s.

Comment: Did you try to calculate it manually? What was the outcome? Definitely found one bug already: it should be `Tcr4 <- 0.30/(1 + 1.2*D)`

Comment: Also, are you sure that the grain size is 1.6e-4 *microns*? That is 1.6e-10 metre, or about an Angstrom and a half, less than a size of an atom. A bacteria has a couple of microns; very fine sand has about 100 microns.

Comment: Please check your units, you have some values in microns, some in centimeters, some in meters, good thing that you don't use furlongs per fortnight ;-)

Comment: Another error: instead of `D2 <- (p*v)^2`, it should be `D2 <- p * (v^2)

Comment: I comment on the deleted answer (feel free to include it as the edit to your post as additional explanation). I don't think that your R skills are here the problem; but before you even start writing code, take a paper and pencil and (maybe) a calculator and try to make sure that your calculations work out. That is what I would do.

Answer (score 2):

OK, so let us try it from start.

```
p <- 1027.4     #water density (m^3)
ps <- 2650      #grain density (m^3)
g <- 9.81       #acceleration due to gravity (m/s^2)
v <- 1.4313e-6  #kinematic viscosity of water  (m^2/s)
z100 <- 100     #level above seabed (cms)
d <- 1.64e-4    #variable (mean grain size in microns)
```

This last value is incorrect if the mean grain size is supposed to be in microns. It is in meters.

```
D <- d * (g * (ps - p) / (p * v^2))^(1/3)
```

The result is 3.22. There was an error in your formula; `(p * v)^2` instead of `p * (v^2)`.

```
Tcr <- g * (ps - p) * d * (.3 / (1 + 1.2 * D) + .055 * (1 - exp(-.02 * D)) )
```

Again, there was an error in your formula: `.3/1 + 1.2 * D` instead of `.3/(1 + 1.2 * D)`. The result is .17.

```
Ucr <- sqrt(Tcr / p)
```

Result is .01.

```
z0 = d / 12
```

Result is 1.37E-5.

```
Ue <- Ucr / .41 * log(z100 / z0)
```

Result is .50. Not sure why we calculate it, however. Are we supposed to compare it with Uset?

```
 Uset <- v / d * ( sqrt(10.36^2 + 1.049 * D^3) - 10.36)
```

Result is .01 (.0137014).

This is not what you say you should get, but it is different from what you are getting. Also, assuming it is not *centimeters* but *meters* per second, then it is about 1 cm per second.

Now, let us check the units. Firstly, you need to be more careful when you specify the units. Water and grain density is not `m^3`; it is `kg * m^-3`.

First, D. The p's are silent (present in both the numerator and the denominator):

```
m * (m * s^-2 / (m^4 * s^-2))^(1/3) = 
m * (1/m^3)^(1/3) = m / m = 1
```

OK, unitless.

Next, Tcr: the whole right part of the formula is unitless (depends only on D). Otherwise,

```
m * s^-2 * kg * m^-3 * m = (m * kg * s^-2) * m^-2 = N / m^2.
```

OK, also OK.

OK, the formula for Uset now. Again, right part of the right side of the equation is unitless. The rest is

```
m^2 * s / m = m / s
```

At least the units check out.

Hope this helps (somehow).